# Linux: Automatically restart 3rd party process once pegged at 100%

Tags: linux, process-monitoring

Is there any generic way to monitor a process and restart it automatically if it's pegged at 100% CPU for over x seconds?

I'm battling some bugs in Mono's fastcgi server and while I search for a fix (analyzing stack traces) I'm looking for a workaround that will automatically detect it being stuck and restart it with the same command line parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MONIT](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Sample configuration:

```
check process example-server with pidfile /var/run/example-server.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/example-server start" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/example-server stop"
  if cpu > 90% for 3 cycles then restart
```

See Also:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/97541/kill-process-with-high-cpu-usage-after-x-time
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784468/monitor-and-kill-runaway-processes-using-100-io
3. http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Worst case scenario was to write a light wrapper around `pidstat`, but this looks good.